# Android: out of memory error when infinite activities?

Tags: android

I create an instance from activity A to B, then in activity B I create another instance of activity A (I want to keep the previous A in history). I keep creating instance and I have a history stack from Activity A -> B -> A -> B -> A.....and after like 20 times, the system looks like need more memory and will kill the first activity A, then B (it calls onDestroy() from Log)...each at a time when I create each activity. I never have any memory issue in this scenario. But if I suddenly create an activity C which has lots of images that requires large memory, it will throw an Out of Memory Error: VM wont let us to allocate 70k bytes something like that.

So anyone know when will system kill an activity? Does it kill only 1 activity each time? How can I let the system give me more memory before I start activity C? Do I have a memory leak on this? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Android does not kill activities unless memory is demanded.  They simply remain in memory, paused.  If you are switching from Activity A to B and back, Android is simply changing which is visible and onResume()d - they are not being killed (to read more on this search on Android Activity Stack).  A memory error on activity C probably is entirely an issue within C.  Depending on your situation, it may be easy to change the AndroidManifest just to test launching C directly... you're likely to get the same result.  FYI.. call finish() to exit an Activity manually and free resources.

Comment: I am sorry I did not make this question clear. I actually create another new instance from B to A and keep adding activity to the stack tree. And after I stack up to 20 times, the system looks like more memory is needed and kill the FIRST activity(A), then if I add 1 more activity, it will kill the SECOND activity(B) etc. The activity C is fine before I add 20 activites in stack.

Comment: heheh.. what I'm reading is "I've got a really unusual case (with unclear goals) leading to Out of Memory, but C works normally otherwise."   You're right, the question is not clear - what is your issue?  Including the entire stack trace and error might help.

Comment: In my case, activities that are at the bottom of the stack aren't even killed - the app just crashes out of memory. :(